# How to initialize a field in a struct from another struct? C

Tags: c

So im new to C programming and my assignment is to write a function(Max_way) that prints the driver who had the total of longest trips.
im using these 2 structs:

```
#define LEN 8  
typedef struct  
{  
    unsigned ID;  
    char name[LEN];  
}Driver;

typedef struct  
{  
    unsigned T_id;  
    char T_origin[LEN];  
    char T_dest[LEN];  
    unsigned T_way;  
}Trip;
```

and a function to determine the total trips of a certain driver:

```
int Driver_way(Trip trips[], int size, unsigned id)  
{  
    int km=0;  
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  
    {  
        if (id == trips[i].T_id)  
        {  
            km = km + trips[i].T_way;  
        }

    }
    return km;
}
```

but when im trying to print the details of a specific driver from an array of drivers, i receive the correct ID, the correct distance of km, but the driver's name is not copied properly and i get garbage string containing 1 character instead of 8.
i've also tried `strcpy(max_driver.name,driver[i].name)` with same result.

```
void Max_way(Trip trips[], int size_of_trips, Driver drivers[], int size_of_drivers)  
{  
    int *km;  
    int max = 0;  
    Driver max_driver;  
    
    km = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (sizeof(drivers) / sizeof(Driver)));
    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_drivers; i++)
    {
        km[i] = Driver_way(trips, sizeof(trips), drivers[i].ID);
        for (int j = 1; j < size_of_drivers; j++)
        {
            if (km[j] > km[j - 1])
            {
                max = km[j];
                max_driver.ID = drivers[i].ID;
                max_driver.name = drivers[i].name;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The driver who drove the most is:\n%d\n%s\n%d km\n", max_driver.ID, max_driver.name, max);
}
```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `(sizeof(drivers) / sizeof(Driver))` is not what you expect. You probably should use `size_of_drivers` instead.

Comment: same for `sizeof(trips)`. When you pass arrays to a function, they decay to a pointer to the first element, so `sizeof` here is giving you the size of a pointer (most likely 4 or 8 depending on your architecture), not the size of your array.

Comment: But either way, all of those sizes are equilivent, the issue here is how do i copy the driver's name into the specific Driver type in the function?
'max_driver.ID = drivers[i].ID;' this line works
   
this one doesnt 'max_driver.name = drivers[i].name;'

Comment: A C string is an array of characters, and you need to copy all of them. A simple assignment is not enough.

Comment: Use `strcpy()` to copy strings.  You have a useless `==` (instead of `=`) in the code (`max_driver.name == drivers[i].name;`), but using `=` would not work either.  Alternatively, and better, simply use structure assignment: `max_driver = drivers[i];` — about the only place where C deigns to copy an array for you.

Comment: i've tried 'strcpy' with the same result.
same with 'max_driver = drivers[i]'    :(

Comment: You need to fix the size errors already mentioned, as they create bugs whose effects can be felt later on, like `strcpy` appearing not to work. Look at your `km = (int*)malloc(...)` line. Assuming you're using an x64 system, `sizeof(drivers)` is 8, assuming no padding on your struct and 4 byte `int`s, `sizeof(Driver)` is 12. With integer division, 8/12 == 0, so that whole thing evaluates to `malloc(0)`, giving you no space for `km`. Accessing `km[i]` and similar invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some sample data (2-5 rows of driver data; 5-20 rows of trip data) and the expected output from that.  That is part of producing an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  Even with the data, we have to guess how you're reading the data, etc.  It would be better/simpler to build the program with hard-wired arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Note that one cannot copy a string using a simple assignment operator; you must use `strcpy` (or similar) as follows:

```
if (km[j] > km[j - 1]) {
    max = km[j];
    max_driver.ID = drivers[i].ID;
    strcpy(max_driver.name,drivers[i].name);
}
```

Also note that since you were using `==`, this was not even a simple assignment, put a comparison. Changing to `==` likely fixed a compile-time error, but it did NOT give you what you want.

Comment: i've tried strcpy and it gives the same result